# Adding service reference to VB.NET project missing nested classes

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, service-reference

Having trouble adding a service reference for a vb project in vs2010. I'm able to add the service reference but some of the nested classes (class.nestedclass) are missing. These classes show up fine if I add the service reference in c# project.

I don't have access to the wcf service code, so it's hard to know exactly how the service is setup.

After some testing this is what was happening:

```
public partial class OuterClass
{
    public Nested nested { get; set; }

    public class Nested
    {
        public string prop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When you reference this code from a vb project (service reference or otherwise) you can't see the Nested class because of the case sensitivity issue

Works fine in the c# world, not so much in vb. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long shot, but are there nested classes with the same name, but different case within the outer class?  This will work fine from C#, but since VB is case-insensitive, it will regard those 2 classes as a conflict (and will not provide any intellisense for either).

Comment: I was just about to answer my own question, but you beat me to it! Yes, that's exactly the problem. Doesn't seem to be any way around it.

Comment: To be more clear, the conflict was between the nested class name and the name of a property of the outerclass.